# Eclipse properties file issue

Tags: eclipse, jboss, properties-file

I am trying to add a propery to properties file. When I click add button nothing happens. Also when I click source and write some property the editor shows but when I save it, what I write disappears. But when I open the property file with notepad++ it shows what I write. I have done some research but I couldn't find anything. What can be the problem with eclipse?

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: The standard properties file editor doesn't have an 'add' button, so which editor is this?

Comment: I have added an screenshot

Comment: JBoss editor is the editor

Comment: it would be great if you can add a bug on https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBIDE since this should of course not happen ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the default editor:

Window > Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations

If you change it to text editor, you can edit it without any problems.